# Links in Rows not working in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, hyperlink, html-table

I have an asp.net application that pulls data from a data base and puts it into a table.  I have it set so that if the user clicks anywhere in the row that the link works.  Basically the code is like this:

```
          <a href="showthisjob.aspx<tr>
          <td align="left">stuff</td>
          <td align="left">stuff</td>
          <td align="left">stuff</td>
         </tr></a>
```

This works fine in IE but in Chrome and Firefox the link doesn't work.  Can someone tell me why? My students need to fix this for a web design competition.

Comment: Well, there's a missing close-quote and close-angle bracket after "aspx". Surely that's not it?

Comment: Missing quote and close angel bracket on your <a> tag. Then <tr> is not a child element of <a>, this is only working in IE. Instead of <a> add event on your <tr> which is onclick="location.href = 'showthisjob.aspx'". Add style="cursor: pointer;" if you want look it like a link.

Comment: Never, ever look to IE as a reference for how things work. As the answers are saying, that markup is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

By the HTML standards, a `<tr>` is not a valid child element of an `<a>` tag, an `<a>` tag can only contain other in-line elements (such as a `<span>`, but excluding another `<a>` tag) and/or text. IE is basically just more forgiving and follows what it thinks you were trying to do instead of what you should really be allowed to do. You can experiment to see what the other browsers will actually allow you to stuff inside an `<a>` and work, but if this is for a web design competition I wouldn't recommend it.

To get similar functionality while following the standards, you would probably need to use an onClick event and a nested table, or better yet use `<div>`'s if you can afford the learning curve since this is for a competition. If not, something like:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td onClick="location.href='showthisjob.aspx'">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">stuff</td>
                <td align="left">stuff</td>
                <td align="left">stuff</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
....
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, to begin with, I hope this typo isn't in your acutal code: you missed the closing `>` for the `<a>` tag.

```
<a href="showthisjob.aspx><tr>
   <td align="left">stuff</td>
   <td align="left">stuff</td>
   <td align="left">stuff</td>
</tr></a>
```

But indeed you cant link tables like that. I suppose this has to do with the browser, and the fact IE usually works different than other browsers in terms of HTML standards. I dont think you can nest `<tr>` on an `<a>`, but tell that to Microsoft...

I suggest putting the `<a>` inside each `<td>`.